# FCM Custom Notification Icon in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, android-layout, firebase-cloud-messaging

good morning all,

I'm using firebase cloud messaging to send notifications but I'm trying to change its icon and can't do it

I'm trying a lot of solutions but no one is working for me such as :

1-

```
<meta-data
  android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
  android:resource="@mipmap/ic_notification" />
```

2-
changing launcher icon

3- modify the `launch_background.xml` and make the transparent

and a lot of solution, could anyone help me, please?

Comment: you can generate icon from here https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_ac_unit  and apply in this tag <meta-data
  android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
  android:resource="@mipmap/ic_notification" />

Comment: it's the first solution I wrote and doesn't work for me

Comment: did you create icon by self ?

Comment: yes, it's a custom icon

Comment: then is it not looking proper ?

Comment: IDK, but I'm trying to select ClipArt and It's giving me no icon. it was transparent

and the same if I select text

Comment: you can select "Image" option

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244985/discussion-between-saayeed-m-daawoud-and-hardik-mehta).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to set custom notification and custom sound or custom icon via local notification while using push notification in flutter.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[project detail](https://github.com/harunayyildiz/meplanner)

Comment: it would be better to write it, it is impossible to copy from image

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. My icon gets gray on some devices. Main issue is on the icon background.

Adding this metadata to the manifest worked for me. & remember your icon background must be transparent.

```
<!--notification icon-->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/bell" />
```

And if you want to change the color, add this metadata to your manifest.

```
<!--notification color-->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Comment: for notification color, can you provide more details like what is @color/colorPrimary?