# Does anyone know how to dynamically change the notification icon in flutter with FCM?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

How do other mainstream apps send different pictures in the icon of notification depending on the notification. Like some apps will display a user profile pic when the user sent you a message. I couldn't find anything related to this topic just on how to display pictures but what I'm asking for is the icon itself.

I tried looking everywhere and couldn't find anything about this topic, as if it were impossible.
I tried running the notification service extension in Swift but no luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable to set custom notification and custom sound or custom icon via local notification while using push notification in flutter.

```
var initializationSettingsAndroid = const AndroidInitializationSettings('ic_launcher');
```

You should use your project root image under:

```
android>app>src>main>res>drawable/ic_launcher
```

You can check [FCM Custom Notification Icon in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72361099/fcm-custom-notification-icon-in-flutter)